# How do i search for the file names that match the pattern we set and write the output to a text file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Example: /apps/mft/local/tmp/folder1/folder2

Let say I have many files at random in folder 1 and folder 2. My requirement is to find the files that match the pattern $DAY-*log.xml* and write the result file names to a text file. Which command should i use in the bash script to perform this task. Please help.

Comment: `find` is the command you are looking for

Comment: Unless i am in the actual folder, find is not working. I want a command that can recursively find all the files with in the sub folders and fetch and print the results in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

`find -name "$DAY-log.xml" > listOfFiles.txt`

It will recursively find the pattern that you want, starting from the current directory, and output all the result to the listOfFiles.txt file.

If you want, you can even give a starting path like this:

`find /path/where/to/start -name "$DAY-log.xml" > listOfFiles.txt`